# Flutter push notifications offline on backgroud

Tags: flutter, notifications, offline

I am trying to make a new todo tasks app and its offline no intternet needed...

I want to get reminded when the tasks time is up

i tried using local notification it worked as showing notification but for my phone as the README section of the package said that it doesnt work for everybody's phone for such android things... So when i terminate my app or having it on my backgroud and wait for the schedule notification nothing appear...

So any idea of how i can let my app work on backgroud

Answer (score 0, accepted):

for the solution i used workmanager so it run my app after a while in the background and push my local notification to the user

welp its hard to it for every 1 sec cause the work manager only make a  loop and activate every 15 min..

workmanager is a flutter package you can use for free :3